# qemu live migration using file descriptor

Tags: migration, qemu, kvm

I am trying to do live migration in qemu. In my knowledge there are 4 ways of doing live migration

1. Using tcp connection
2. Using exec
3. Using proc
4. Using fd

Though the syntax for live migration for tcp and exec is given here http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Migration , I am unable to find live migration syntax using the  fd (file descriptor) option.
Could someone please tell how to pass fd parameter to qemu?